# Parallax.js cross-browser issues

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, parallax, parallax.js

I am new to parallax effects, and I am using parallax.js to work on a new design.

Live example here:

http://codepen.io/simonmoon/pen/f45f0d4ee0024d268d0b5ce5f4107a5d

The issue that I am having is that different browser are displaying the scene completely differently, when it is viewed full screen. It works as intended on chrome, but on firefox the images are larger, the positioning is different, and the body is not hiding the overflow - allowing you to scroll the page which is not intended. In IE the images are larger and the 3 star layers do not move.  I have done some research on google but cant find any relevant solutions, and I am honestly not sure what might be causing the differences.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For completions sake here is the html(jade)

```
ul#scene
  li.layer(data-depth="0.00")
  li.layer(data-depth="0.10")
    div.starsbg
  li.layer(data-depth="0.40")
    div.starsmg
  li.layer(data-depth="0.60")
    div.starsfg
  li.layer(data-depth="1.40")
    div.chartouter
  li.layer(data-depth="1.50")
    div.chartinner     
  li.layer(data-depth="1.80")
    div.palmistry 
  p.title.
    Salt Of The Moon
  div.texthalo
  li.layer(data-depth="14.20")
```

The css(stylus)

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito)

background-size()
  -webkit-background-size arguments
  -moz-background-size arguments
  -o-background-size arguments
  background-size arguments

box-shadow()
  -webkit-box-shadow arguments
  -moz-box-shadow arguments
  box-shadow arguments

body
  padding 0
  margin 0
  height 0px
  width 100%
  background url('http://i60.tinypic.com/5ofqs5.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed
  background-size(cover)
  overflow hidden
  -moz-overflow hidden
  font-family 'Nunito' sans-serif

.textcontain
  absolute top 350px
  text-align center
  width 100%

#scene
  absolute top 0 left 0
  width 100%
  height 1400px
  margin auto

li.layer
  width 100%
  height 100%
  list-style-type none

.chartouter
  background url('http://i60.tinypic.com/21llf09.png') no-repeat top center
  position absolute
  top 50% 
  left 50%
  width 880px
  height 880px
  margin-top -440px
  margin-left -440px

.chartinner
  background url('http://i59.tinypic.com/1z4e5cj.png') no-repeat center
  width 400px
  height 400px
  absolute top 458px left 50%
  margin-left -200px


.palmistry
  background url('http://i57.tinypic.com/2i0vrye.png') no-repeat top center
  width 600px
  height 500px
  absolute top 414px left 50%
  margin-left -315px

.texthalo
  box-shadow(0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1))
  absolute top -200px left -5px
  border-radius 50%
  width 40px
  height 300px

.starsbg
  background url('http://i60.tinypic.com/abi9o1.png') center center fixed
  background-size(cover)
  width 100%
  height 100%

.starsmg
  background url('http://i61.tinypic.com/2z4wylh.png') left center fixed
  background-size(cover)
  width 100%
  height 100%

.starsfg
  background url('http://i58.tinypic.com/280jybr.png') center center fixed
  background-size(cover)
  width 100%
  height 100%

.title
  width 10%
  margin-left auto
  margin-right auto
  text-align center
  absolute top -150px
  font-size 3.2em
  -webkit-font-smoothing antialiased
  text-shadow rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0px 0px 20px
  color white
  letter-spacing 8px
```

and the javascript(note: parrallax.js is being loaded by codepen in the above link, the extra code is a supposed firefox parrallax rendering fix I found [here](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/faster-scrolling-parallax-websites-in-firefox/).

```
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
var parallax = new Parallax(scene);

(function(doc) {

  var root = doc.documentElement;

  // Not ideal, but better than UA sniffing.
  if ("MozAppearance" in root.style) {

    // determine the vertical scrollbar width
    var scrollbarWidth = root.clientWidth;
    root.style.overflow = "scroll";
    scrollbarWidth -= root.clientWidth;
    root.style.overflow = "";

    // create a synthetic scroll event
    var scrollEvent = doc.createEvent("UIEvent")
    scrollEvent.initEvent("scroll", true, true);

    // event dispatcher
    function scrollHandler() {
      doc.dispatchEvent(scrollEvent)
    }

    // detect mouse events in the document scrollbar track
    doc.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      if (e.clientX > root.clientWidth - scrollbarWidth) {
        doc.addEventListener("mousemove", scrollHandler, false);
        doc.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
          doc.removeEventListener("mouseup", arguments.callee, false);
          doc.removeEventListener("mousemove", scrollHandler, false);
        }, false)
      }
    }, false)

    // override mouse wheel behaviour.
    doc.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
      // Don't disable hot key behaviours
      if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey) {
        root.scrollTop += e.detail * 16;
        scrollHandler.call(this, e);
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    }, false)

  }
})(document);
```